# java - chat program hangs during file transfer?

Tags: java

i have a java chat server & client, that works fine. I made a server to client file transfer program separately, it is also working fine. But when i try to integrate the file transfer into chat, the file is getting transferred, but during that time, the chat program just freezes, so much that i can't even type a thing into the chat box, and when transfer gets over, things get normal. how to make it normal, like chatting and file transfer is taking place side by side, none gets affected by the other?

My file transfer has while loops on both server and client, i wanted to know that is this because of while loops, should i create threads on both file transfer's server and client code. 
My Chat System is like, on server,user connects, threads starts on server for that user, for reading from user, it then sends these messages from user to everyone. 
On client, threads are for reading from server, when user types messages, it send it to server, which then return messages to everyone connected.

i think the problem is on Client side, as i just tested this on internet with my friend, i was the server, for both Chat & File Transfer, my chat box was fine, i was able to type, but his chat client freezd for the time file transfer took place.

i don't know which part of code is causing this, so i'll update this with code, as soon as someone asks for it..

Thanks,
Any help wud be appreciated.

**[EDIT--FILE TRANSFER ON CLIENT]**

```
public class FileClient{


JFrame jfr;
JTextField Jtf = new JTextField(4);
public static void main (String [] args ) {

 // new FileClient().go();

 }

public void go(String ip){
    try{
    JFrame jfr = new JFrame("File Transfer");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel jl = new JLabel("Progress:");
    jfr.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    panel.add(jl);
    panel.add(Jtf);
    Jtf.setEditable(false);
    jfr.setSize(200,70);
    jfr.setVisible(true);
    jfr.setDefaultCloseOperation(jfr.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int read;
    int totalRead = 0;
    try{
    Socket sock = new Socket(ip,4243);
    System.out.println("Connecting...");
    InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new ProgressMonitorInputStream(jfr,"reading",is));

    byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [512];
    int buff =1024;
    byte[] nameByte = new byte [50];
    byte[] nameByteSize = new byte [2];
    byte[] Size = new byte [10];
    byte[] SizeSize =new byte [1];

    int num = is.read(nameByte,0,50);
    int nameSize = is.read(nameByteSize,0,2);
    int sz = is.read(Size,0,10);
    int yy = is.read(SizeSize,0,1);
    float w;

    String Size1 = RemoveNameStuffing(new String(Size),new String(SizeSize));
    int tt = Integer.parseInt(Size1);
    System.out.println("tt"+tt);
     name"+new String(nameByte));
    String name = RemoveNameStuffing(new String(nameByte),new String(nameByteSize));
    File f1=new File(name);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f1);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

    while ((read = bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length)) != -1) {
            bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , read);
            totalRead += read; 
            w=((float)totalRead/tt)*100;
            System.out.println("progress:"+w+"%");
            Jtf.setText(w+"%");
    }


    bos.flush();
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println(end-start);
    bos.close();
    sock.close();
    }catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace();}
}

public static String RemoveNameStuffing(String s, String n){

    s=s.substring(0,Integer.parseInt(n));
    System.out.println("s:"+s);

    return s;

}
```

}

**[EDIT--THIS IS HOW I AM CALLING FILE TRANSFER CODE INTO CHAT CLIENT]**

```
public class AcceptFileButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      FileCl.go(JTip.getText());
    }

}
```

**[EDIT--FILE TRANSFER SERVER CODE--BUFFER SIZE 512]**

```
//Waiting for connection
//Sending name in bytes
//While{
   send files as bytes
   }
```

**[CHAT SERVER  WHERE ABOVE (FT SERVER) CODE IS CALLED]**

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        FileSv.go();

    }
```

and my server also freezes as soon as i press the button, even when the FT server has not even got a connection(i think this cud help).

i have a chat server and client, both having threads to read from each other. i tried to integrate my File transfer server and client into existing chat server and chat client.
initially when user connects to chat server, it starts a thread for it. now to send a file to that user, i created 1 button on server(file send) and 1 on client(accept file), now as i click onto "file send" on server, my File transfer server code gets executed, and File transfer Sever wait for a connection on different port(my chat server now freezes, it has a textField, which is unresponsive now), now if the user with whom i am chatting perfectly, clicks on "accept file" File transfer client code gets executed. FT server starts sending bytes, FT client rcvs it. both the server and client CHAT window becomes unresponsive for the time transfer takes place, and whatever i have sent from the client side chat box during transfer, gets updated after transfer.
This is to clear the confusion. even if this doesn't help, i will upload whole code(which is too big)

Comment: Is it the same thread handling chat and file transfer (on client or server) ?

Comment: Without seeing your code, we would be just speculating.

Comment: Sounds like you're running the file transfer on the same thread as the chat. You'll need a separate thread for the file transfer, or one thread per file transfer if you're going to handle multiple simultaneous transfers.

Comment: @Pavel NO, as i mentioned earlier that my chat system works on threads, while my file transfer(which was made completely separated) is having while loops to send the bytes, and also both Chat and File transfer works on different ports..

Comment: @NickNikolaou what part of code should i paste here, my chat was working fine, it is my File Transfer chat program that after integration is causing this...shud i start with File Transfer code?

Comment: @Baqueta chat clients has 1 thread to read from server, and when clicked on a button on the clientchat window,  FileTransferClient side is initiated, which works on while loop to read byte from server.

Comment: If your file sending code is not threaded, it could be hogging all the CPU, leaving your chat thread starved of resources.

Comment: @mcfinnigan +1. OP are you sure that the file transfer is running on another thread?

Comment: @mcfinnigan earlier when i was testing this on localhost, i tht may be this is because of both sending and rcvng is done on one computer, but i just tested this on internet, and my friend having abv File transfer client  & the chat client was having problems, and me on server and another chat client to chat, was just totally fine, i didn't felt a bit on the server. so i think the prblm is on client.

Comment: @NikharSharma Paste the rest of the project's code.

Comment: @mcfinnigan i already mentioned that, i have a chat client having 1 thread to read from server after connection working on 1 port. i integrated File transfer client to it, which is reading bytes frm File transfer server with WHILE loops, no thread in file transfer client or on server, FT working totally on WHILE loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, to expand my comment - you say `when clicked on a button on the clientchat window, FileTransferClient side is initiated, which works on while loop to read byte from server.`

Are you running your file transfer code in the Swing Event thread?  If so, you need to wrap it inside a Runnable object, ensure that its yielding up some processing time between iterations of the while loops, and invoke it using SwingUtilities.

If you're starting a separate thread on the button press in order to transfer the file, you still need to yield up processing time between loops of your sending loop or you're not yielding any processing time to the chat processing threads.

edit: amend your action listener call to do the following:

```
 @Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
      new Runnable() { 
         public void run() {
            FileCl.go(JTip.getText());
         }
      }
   );
}
```

What this does is move the CPU and IO intensive processing of your file download into a new thread, external to the Swing event thread.

Comment: no, i havent use any kind of threading system in my File Transfer code. i made it separately, using WHILE loops on sever/client to send/rcv bytes.

Comment: And I'm guessing you're also calling go() from inside an ActionListener on a button.

Comment: Is that why the small jframe i created above to have %completed, doesnt even show up untill the FT. Is over?

Comment: And also 1 more ques..how come it is in swing event thread, when i havent used any swing in FT code?

Comment: Probably, yes.  Swing needs processing time in order to repaint itself and render any new components; by running your file download in the event thread you're preventing the processing of any other events on Swing's event queue.  As to your second question - you're launching your FT from inside a Swing actionhandler - hence, that code is being executed by a Thread which runs inside the Swing framework.

Comment: Nothing happend, i tried this time with two chat clients, on one i accepted the file, it freezd, while the other is working fine..

Answer (score 3):

You are experiencing the tell-tale sign of using synchronous operations while you want asynchronous operations.

My guess is that you have either a single thread for your application or a single thread for your remote communication. You are likely not using java's nio classes for asynchronous communication.

You could either look into the nio classes or execute your current file-sending and file-receiving code in a separate thread.

The implementation for the former can be found in a decent nio tutorial (here's [one](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/index.html)).

A common implementation for the latter is to use the command pattern for sending messages/files, and a command queue with producer/consumer threads. You can treat the "Runnable" interface as your Command class.

```
public class MessageCommand implements Runnable {
    private String message;
    public MessageCommand(String message) { this.message = message; }
    public void run() { /* code to send the message goes here */ }
}

public class FileCommand implements Runnable {
    private File file; /* or byte[] or whatever */
    public MessageCommand(File file) { this.file = file; }
    public void run() { /* code to send the file goes here */ }
}
```

Then have some kind of `Queue<Runnable>`, possibly ConcurrentLinkedQueue, that takes objects of these types, and use the producer/consumer. Note that you will also need to spin off a separate thread on the receiving part of the code as well. Otherwise, you will be able to send asynchronously, but will block while receiving (which might be ok for messages, but annoying for files).

Comment: ok, i am totally new to nio, but do u think that if i start a thread on client side to accept file from server, which is also running a thread to read chat messages from socket from server, will make a difference? That means, i have now, on server, 1 thread to read chat messages from client, and 1 thread to send bytes to client(on different port). and the same on client, 2 threads, 1 to read from server, and 1 to receive bytes?

Comment: I think it is probably fine to block files with files and chat with chat (you want the chat ordered anyway, and having one thread send the chat messages in order makes that code easier). I actually started my answer before you posted code, so I didn't know anything about your program structure when I wrote the above. My answer's lack of specificity reflects that.

Comment: yes, i felt that, but i will study nio. DO u have any guesses what's wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately, without looking at all the code, I don't. Do you have a debugger or profiler? You should be able to figure out where the time is being spent in the code.

Comment: which part do u want me to upload?

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually have time to look through all of the code. I would suggest that if you upload code, you do 2 things. 1. spend some time refactoring. A simple variable renaming would help readability a lot (name by purpose, not by type). `jtf` doesn't tell people a lot, and makes it harder for outsiders to offer help. 2. upload the code that actually dispatches the threads. You claim it's multi-threaded, but I don't see a thread anywhere, and your problem sounds exactly like synchronous operation issue.

Comment: threads are in chat client & server, not in FT client & server, but i am calling FT Client & server from inside thread of chat Client & server.